# List files in a folder

Tags: macos, vba, excel, macros

I use the following code to let the user select a folder then list the last time each file within was modified (one column for day and another for time). The third column is for the names of the files.

```
Sub ListFils()
Dim f As Object, fso As Object, flder As Object
Dim folder As String
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
        End
    End If
    folder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents


For Each f In fso.GetFolder(folder).Files
    ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = f.DateLastModified
    ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = f.DateLastModified
    ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = f.Name


Next
Columns("A:C").Columns.AutoFit
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

The code works on Windows but does not work on Mac. Any ideas how I can get it to work?

Comment: "...does not work at all" - Are there errors? Does it run, but skip stuff? Does it not run at all, do you get a notice?  What happens when you run it on a mac?

Comment: Activex objects like the Scripting library are not available on Mac. You should be able to use `Dir()` to do the same thing though.

Comment: @BruceWayne, it gets me nothing. Appears the debug pop up.
@TimWilliams, thank you for the tip, but I am on the first steps of coding, and I don't know how to use it. I tried to use `Dir()`, but I was just able to search files with this command.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said in his comment, the line `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`, and anything that relies on `fso` will not work on mac, but you can use `Dir()` to get file names, and `FileDateTime("filename")` to get the modified date.